# PHP show query result / content short

Tags: php

In my code below, I want to show a small part of $row["content"] so lets just say only 50 words of its full text. How would I be able to do this?

```
<?php
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` = test');

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<h1>'.$row["title"].'</h1><br>'.$row["content"].'';

    }
      }
    }
?>
```

Edited out some coding that might not be needed.

I also tried putting:

```
$pos=strpos($row["content"], ' ', 40);
substr($row["content"],0,$pos);
```

into it, but didnt work.

Comment: you need 50 word or 50 char?

Comment: You never execute the prepared statement.

Comment: @EmilioGort word please. Sorry I should have mentioned this.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Knew I forgot something when I copied it. Just pretend its there.

Comment: @MagNetas's answer didnt work for you?

Comment: @EmilioGort No it didnt, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//demo string taken from lipsum.com
$str = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using \'Content here, content here\', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for \'lorem ipsum\' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don\'t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn\'t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.';

//let's output the "input"
echo 'Original str:<br />' . $str . '<hr />';

$words = str_word_count($str, 2);  ///get the words and their positions in your string

if (count($words) > 50)   //if more than 50 words
{
    $positions = array_keys($words);  //get the positions of the words
    $str = trim(substr($str, 0, $positions[50]));  //get a substring up until position of 51st word and "clear" the whitespace around it
}

//and that's the final string
echo 'Short string: <br />' . $str;
```

If there are more than 50 words you should "extract" 50 words. Otherwise you'll just have your initial string.

Comment: I'll try it out myself once I get back to my computer

Comment: Thankyou, hopefully it can be fixed

Comment: Tested and this is a working example. Actually it was all fine so I'm not sure what didn't work for you. If this doesn't do the trick let me know more details

Comment: Thanks its working. I'm grabbing the string from a database field, which also has images. Is there any way I could get rid of the images from showing?

Comment: This should only work with plain text. You can try using stip_tags to get rid of the html tags in your string.

Comment: This worked, although anyway I could just strip away the <img tag, as some content have embled videos in which I'd like to show

Comment: embeded videos will be treated as words and this solution will not work.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Strip tags worked. and your code worked. Thankyou again.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo '<h1>'.$row["title"].'</h1><br>'.substr($row["content"],0,40).'';
```

Comment: what type of data $row["content"] contains

Comment: What do you mean type of data? like varchar? longtext? If so its longtext